# Question about centering an image having a badbox

Tags: badness

If you have a large image and you get a warning about an overful box then when you try to center that image will you have a result the image centered around it's center or nothing will happen? And why will that be? When that happened to me the image didn't move. Shouldn't be centered around it's center instead?

Comment: overfull boxes always overshoot on the right (more or less true) certainly that is the case in all latex alignments. You should arrange for the box to not be overfull either by scaling the image or by using a lost environment to locally increase the line width.

Comment: Yes that is what I did. But why they overshoot on the right? And except that shouldn't the image be centered around it's center no matter if there is a badbox?

Comment: center works by putting stretch glue as left and right skip so neither can go smaller that 0pt, so the box just sticks out, It could be done differently but would lead to bad layout without warning (eg image off the physical page) overfull boxes are an error the system doesn't go out of its way do do anything nice with them, you're supposed to fix them:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

overfull boxes always overshoot on the right (more or less true) certainly that is the case in all latex alignments.

center works by putting stretch glue as left and right skip so neither can go smaller that 0pt, so the box just sticks out, It could be done differently but would lead to bad layout without warning (eg image off the physical page) overfull boxes are an error the system doesn't go out of its way do do anything nice with them, you're supposed to fix them:-)